GoLand - Go to Test Shortcut
I am new to GoLand. In WebStorm, I use the JS Toolbox plugin to jump to the test file for a given file via shortcut.
How can I achieve the same in GoLand?

You can use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+T on Windows/Linux or Cmd+Shift+T on macOS. This shortcut will toggle between the source file and its corresponding test file if they exist.
